# How to sort du -h --max-depth=1, ordering by folder name?

Tags: linux, du

```
du -h --max-depth=1 July
```

reports:

```
25G     July/02July2015
24M     July/03July2015
18M     July/01July2015
25G     July
```

How to make it sort in the following order (ordering by folder name):

```
18M     July/01July2015
25G     July/02July2015
24M     July/03July2015
25G     July
```

Or even:

```
25G     July
18M     July/01July2015
25G     July/02July2015
24M     July/03July2015
```

How to approach this issue?

Answer (score 4):

```
du -h --max-depth=1 July | sort -k 2
```

will take the output of `du` and sort it on the second field.

Note that sort has a switch called `--month-sort` it migth be usefull as well.